# HTML from ajax request console logs as object

Tags: html, ajax

I am requesting some HTML content via an API using jQuery ajax. The data I get back console logs as an object, even when I parse it with jQuery.

Here is what I am doing

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    success: function(data){

        var html = data
        var parseData = $(html);

        console.log(parseData);


    }
});
```

I have tried `dataType` it made no difference. I have tried to find elements within the data return, but that returns the same.

The data I am returning does not have a doctype, html or body tag.

```
<div class="item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is the data being returned wrong?

**EDIT**
Here is the console log
[image: Screenshot of console log]

Comment: give url is the data of type json

Comment: what did you exactly try with dataType? What is the result of console.log?

Comment: Try https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: @simon I tried dataType: 'html'

Comment: @Pugazh get console logs the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely correct that you get an object in your console.

By default jQuery tries to guess the type of the content (what they call an "intelligent guess") and in your case it probably thinks this is HTML. Probably - because you did not provide us with an example of the thing you are asking.

After jQuery thinks this is HTML, it wraps it into a jQuery object, which I guess you see in your console.

Try to call `console.log(data.find(".item").length)` - I have a feeling the result will be 3.

To get the pure HTML you must use a `dataType: "text"`. This will stop jQuery from attempts of parsing the data and will give you the raw string result.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using text. Maybe my issue is more to do with jQuery being able to manipulate these elements. I am doing var entries = parseData.find('.items'); But when i check entries.length it returns 0. I can output the return to the DOM. They are hidden with CSS and I want to loop through them to add a class to show them. But i am not able to pass the new elements to a function to do that because it returns as 0

Comment: When I console log the $(data).find('.item'), it returns this : [prevObject: n.fn.init[59], context: undefined, selector: ".item", jquery: "2.1.3", constructor: function…]

Comment: well this is a pure jQuery object. Could you look inside and try to find your elements?

Comment: However this does not return length. I have been reading up on prevObject. I am trying to append the .find() elements to the DOM

Comment: could you try to replace `.find` with `.filter` and check the length? The first one is traversing the children and the second one is just filtering the current level. As far as you have no wrapping div around your three divs, they should be on the top-level, so `.filter` should catch them

Comment: Thanks for explaining that. I don't understand why it is not working as expected. Should i wrap it in a container div, would that solve it? I tried filter but it returned no results

Comment: The best way to do is to return a JSON and construct the result on JS side: this will split the server and client side problems. But your problem now is just a sort of misunderstanding... If you gave us some page where the error could be reproduced...

Comment: Thanks. I will look to handle it a different way.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxUrl,
    dataType: "html"
})
.done(function( html ) {
    console.log( html );
});
```

Comment: I tried done and it made no difference. It maybe I am misunderstanding what I am doing when jquery gets the data. I want to find certain elements, add them to the dom, and then add a class to them.